# Using org-roam tags when org publishing

Tags: org-mode, org-publish, org-roam

When publishing it's possible to get a list of filetags for an org note by doing something like `(org-export-data (plist-get info :filetags) info)` in `publish.el` and loop over them to create markup. I use [org-roam](https://github.com/org-roam/org-roam/tree/v1.2.3) and was wondering if there is a way to do something similar with the `+#roam_tags:` property. Just switching `:filetags` for `:roam_tags` doesn't work - no error, it's just empty I think. Could anyone offer some advice on how I might approach this?

FYI I asked this question on the [org-mode sub reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/orgmode/comments/mte9ok/how_to_do_stuff_with_roam_tags_when_publishing/) as well but posting here as well.

Comment: Just as an FYI, in org-roam v2, `roam_tags` are deprecated in favor of regular org-mode tags (via `filetags` or plain heading tags).

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting with custom backends using `org-export-define-derived-backend`, I learned that we can define custom properties and reference their values in the way my question states. For example:

We can derive a backend from the existing one and provide customizations. In this case, we can define a custom property mapped to the export property.

```
(org-export-define-derived-backend 'my-custom-backend 'slimhtml
  :options-alist
  '((:roam_tags "ROAM_TAGS" nil nil split)))
```

Now, with `my-custom-backend` defined, invoking `(plist-get info :roam_tags)` returns a list of the `#+roam_tags`.
Also, we can access the roam tags with `(org-publish-find-property entry :roam_tags project 'my-custom-backend)`

See https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-export-reference.html
and http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Var/org-export-options-alist.html for more details like the additional arguments.